# High cpu utilization in c++ module

Tags: c++, linux

I have C++ module , for a particular flow the CPU utilization goes to 70% and
  comes back.

Wanted to know is there a **way to find out what is making the cpu utilization**
  high.

I checked through the program and there is a while loop , but it is executed 
  only once. 
  Any command or way to find out the culprit.

Thanks in advance

SKP

Comment: Profile your program with [Callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) and visualise the output with [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html).  It will show you where the program is spending its time.

Comment: Note that a high CPU% is generally a _good_ thing. It means the CPU isn't  waiting on data from disk or RAM.